# Seamless page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've seen some similar questions about this around here but I didn't see anything that might be able to help me here. I am making a web site and I want each page to fade in on load and fade out when someone clicks a link. I have that down with jQuery but between the pages there is a white flash before the pages load. I tried moving around my javascript but in some cases the page didn't load correctly. I'm a bit new to this so I may need a bit of explanation on any possible solutions.

Here is the live site:
http://codyshawdesign.com

The HTML is valid in 4.01 Transitional. I've heard about something like Ajax or pagination but I am unsure how to implement those or what I would have to do to put it in my site or if it would even be the most ideal solution. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should really go through your code and add semi-colons everywhere. You're missing them on most lines of code, meaning your site will break on non-modern browsers.

Comment: Are you talking about the javascript? I was planning on minifying it once I got the sites code complete so hopefully that will do the trick, but thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't take shortcuts, and I also would write the language the way it was meant to be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you only update a portion of a page, not the whole page? Now you have many full scale pages with different file names. The page address changes so the whole page is loaded. It's like refreshing the current with `ctrl+r/cmd+r` page and that isn't very ajaxy.

One solution would be to have a master page which contains all of the common elements between pages such as header, footer and navigation bar. On that page you have a div (or some other area) where you load information dynamically from a different file. What info is loaded could be determined with GET variables via anchor tags or ajax form buttons.

See for example this link and it's demo.
http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

It's pretty basic but it demonstrates the idea not to load the whole page but only a portion of it. Add some styles and you're ready to go.

Sorry if this doesn't help. Maybe there is a way to refresh the whole page without the white flash. Easy solution would be to change the background color to white but then again, it wouldn't be very ajaxy...

Comment: I originally went with the full pages because I read an article that said it is difficult for search engines to pick up on files built with ajax. I wanted there to be the ability to jump effortlessly to the portfolio page without having to go through the home page first, but this code sounds like it works around that. The example on that page is very close to what I was looking for, but when I click a link it reloaded the content I had, but when I clicked it again it loaded the new content (Using Google Chrome). Hopefully I can do some searching around for a workaround to the error in Chrome.

Comment: I found a good solution through the site you referenced. http://cmpolis.github.com/Pagify/#about

Comment: @xistag That's great to know. I forgot about Google's indexing problems concerning dynamically created pages. (I use dynamic content only in intranet where no search engines are allowed.). Here's couple of articles that might be helpful: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/27/searchable-dynamic-content-with-ajax-crawling/, http://arnoldit.com/wordpress/2008/04/20/indexing-dynamic-databased-content/

Answer (score 0):

With do pagination you would have to return all pages right when the the user visits your index.php and then you would use javascript to show and hide the right divs as the user clicks the links in menu, that's not good in your case, it'll make the user wait for the entire site even if he's not willing to look at all of it.

AJAX seems the right way, and u can easily implement it with jQuery load method. Just to get you started:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
    );
});
```

This should cause all your links to replace the content of the pageContent div with the content returned by the link without flashing the screen.

Comment: I added the code to a page called ex.php to see if it would work. I knew it would only duplicate what was in the other files and that I would need to edit the html before it would work completely but the code didn't appear to execute at all. Instead it loaded the full page instead of only replacing the div.